# inverse laplace transform of the ratio of two imcomplete Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, gamma-function

I am struggling to get the inverse Laplace transform of the ratio of two incomplete gamma function as follow.
$\frac{{{\Gamma ^m}\left[ {\alpha, \left( {\frac{1}{\beta } + s} \right)\eta } \right]}}{{{\Gamma ^m}\left( {\alpha, \frac{\eta }{\beta }} \right)}}$

where $m$ is a positive integer,$\alpha$,$\beta$ and $\eta $ are positive real number. $s$ is the complex number frequency parameter of Laplace transform.
The inverse Laplace transform is as follow
$\frac{1}{{2\pi j}}\int_{r - j\infty }^{r + j\infty } {\frac{{{\Gamma ^m}\left( {\alpha ,\left( {\frac{1}{\beta } + s} \right)\eta } \right)}}{{{\Gamma ^m}\left( {\alpha ,\frac{\eta }{\beta }} \right)}}{e^{sx}}ds} $

It seems to be hard work. Do someone have a way to get the result. An approximation is also a good result.

Comment: Ha ha that is so cool that you use $j$ instead of $i$ like I do for the imaginary unit. I'm guessing that that means you do electronics? Also, the bottom incomplete gamma function is simply a constant, correct? So you can move it out of the integral. I'm not sure about the rest though, I'll look into it. Also, is the $M$ term a power? Or a derivative? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the the variable $s$ is in the lower limit and not the integrand? And also, is $m$ a differentiating power? Or just a power? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you guess, I really major in electronics. And yes, the bottom incomplete gamma function can move it out of the integral. The M term is power. About variable s, s is the complex number frequency parameter of Laplace.

Comment: I just need some clarification again

$\displaystyle \Gamma \left( \alpha ,\left(\frac{1}{\beta } +s\right) \eta \right) =\int\limits ^{\infty }_{\left(\frac{1}{\beta } +s\right) \eta } t^{\alpha -1} e^{-t} dt$

But are you sure you didn't make a mistake i your equation and you should have $\displaystyle \Gamma \left(\left(\frac{1}{\beta } +s\right) \eta ,\ \alpha \right) =\int\limits ^{\infty }_{\alpha } t^{\left(\frac{1}{\beta } +s\right) \eta -1} e^{-t} dt$ ?
Because This would make more sense, so I'm not sure if it's just a mistake. 

Sorry for delayed response. Thanks!